# Converting to DateTime in json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the following:

```
{"ts":"2012-04-22 04:14:50,669", "msg":"Hello"}
```

into

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime Ts { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}
```

using

```
var logEntry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogEntry>(line);
```

But get a JsonSerializationException saying "{"Error converting value \"2012-04-22 04:14:28,478\" to type 'System.DateTime'. Line 1, position 31."}. I cannot change the log format.

I think I might need to parse the date string myself using a Converter. However, I cannot find any examples of `JsonConverter` that seem relevant. Specifically how to read the value from the `reader` in the `ReadJson` method.

Are there any simple examples that I should look at? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: This question over at stack apps looks like it does what you need: http://stackapps.com/questions/1175/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-net-datetime/1176

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw it before, but since the code in the ReadJson method is commented out I didn't see it as a very good example.

Comment: Scroll down through the example, there is an uncommented version of the ReadJson method. Either way, the basic principle of the example is sound.

Comment: The comma is because it's the decimal separator. I'm more interested in the general way of helping Json.net parse something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format on your DateTime string uses a comma for the decimal separator (`,478`). You may be able to initialise a `JsonSerializerSettings` object ([documented here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm)) with an appropriate `Culture`, and then deserialise using `DeserializeObject<T>(value, settings)` ([documented here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm)). This would deserialise using the culture you specify rather than the default `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Looks nice. However, my version of json.net (which I currently cannot upgrade for dependency reasons) doesn't have the Culture or Date* properties on JsonSerializerSettings.

Comment: Unfortunate. :/ In that case I guess you're forced down the custom Converter route. Is [this SO entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/608457) useful at all?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the issue is because the value you are getting is using a comma as the decimal separator which suggests it was created in a locale that uses commas (e.g. a lot of European languages other than English). You could try changing your locale to match so that the parsing would work?